# Function map vs protocol implementation

Tags: clojure, idioms

I'm new to clojure and I'm trying to make sense of the different design choices available in different situation. In this particular case I would like to group tightly coupled functionality and make it possible to pass the functions around as a collection.

1. When to use function maps to group tightly related functionality and when to use protocols (+ implementations)?
2. What are the advantages and drawbacks?
3. Is either more idiomatic?

For reference, here are two examples of what I mean. With fn maps:

```
(defn do-this [x] ...)
(defn do-that [] ...)
(def some-do-context { :do-this (fn [x] (do-this x)
                       :do-that (fn [] (do-that) }
```

and in the second case,

```
(defprotocol SomeDoContext
  (do-this[this x] "does this")
  (do-that[this] "does that")

(deftype ParticularDoContext []
  SomeDoContext
  (do-this[this x] (do-this x))
  (do-that[this] (do-that))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you meant by "tightly related functionality". There can be 2 interpretations:

- These set of functions implement a particular component/sub-system of the system. Example: Logging, Authentication etc. In this case you will probably use a clojure namespace (AKA module) to group the related functions rather than using a hash map.
- These set of functions work together on some data structure or type or object etc. In this case you will use Protocol based approach, which allows ad-hoc polymorphism such that new types can also provide this set of functionality. Example: Any interface kind of thing: Sortable, Printable etc.

Comment: So when should function maps be used?

Comment: I personally, would not use a map of functions and only use map for data

Answer (score 1):

Protocols are like `Interfaces` so if what you're trying to create is one, use a protocol.

If you're just trying to group `related functions` somewhere use a `namespace`, it's ok to have your functions floating there attached to no particular `Object`.

It seems to me you're thinking about Objects and using the `map` just to simulate an Object or a struct you're attaching your functions together. Feels unnatural to me unless it's indeed a type or protocol, and you should use `defrecord`, `deftype` and `defprotocol` in those cases.

An example taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437586/clojure-aspects-defprotocol-defrecord) about using `defprotocol` and `defrecord`:

```
(defprotocol IAnimal
  "the animal protocol"
  (inner-report [o] "a report"))

(defrecord Dog []
  IAnimal
  (inner-report [o]
    (println "Woof Woof.\n")))

(defrecord Cat []
  IAnimal
  (inner-report [o]
    (println "Meow Meow.\n")))
```

Answer (score 0):

My first impression would be that the first way is data oriented and the second way is type oriented. So far, I prefer data oriented. 
Perhaps the decision is related with Alan Perlis quote: "It is better to have 100 functions operate on one data structure than 10 functions on 10 data structures."

Comment: Yeah. I've read Rich Hickey's musings on "[On the importance of recognizing and using maps](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/4II-HKr_Pu0)". This makes my type loving, interface centric OO mind hurt a bit; but perhaps it's just a phase ;)